# Optimizing memory usage of an Android sticky background service

Tags: java, android, service

I have a sticky background service which is implemented in the form of an sdk/library. I am trying to minimize the memory usage. I did try using separate processes but Android seems to load a lot of extra possibly belonging to main app using the library. When I use the library with an empty SDKtest app the memory usage comes down to reasonable levels. And this additionally memory traces back to preloaded system drawables but just can't figure out why those are classified as private dirty in one case. So having the service as an external apk solves the issue but as you can guess that's not practical. Any idea how to proceed with this ?

```
** MEMINFO in pid 14571 [org.abc.abc:Service] **
                 Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
              ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap     4481     4308        0     1008     7292     6353      938
Dalvik Heap     5649     5532        0        0     7373     6980      393
Dalvik Other      616      616        0        0                           
      Stack      332      332        0        0                           
  Other dev        5        0        4        0                           
   .so mmap     2623      152     1472     2832                           
  .apk mmap      204        0      128        0                           
  .ttf mmap       56        0       48        0                           
  .dex mmap     1576        0     1484        0                           
  .oat mmap     3467        0     1588        0                           
  .art mmap     2739      760      264        0                           
 Other mmap        6        4        0        0                           
  GL mtrack     3380     3380        0        0                           
    Unknown      166      164        0      144                           
      TOTAL    25300    15248     4988     3984    14665    13333     1331

Objects
             Views:        0         ViewRootImpl:        0
       AppContexts:        3           Activities:        0
            Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
     Local Binders:        8        Proxy Binders:       23
     Parcel memory:       40         Parcel count:       54
  Death Recipients:        0      OpenSSL Sockets:        0

SQL
       MEMORY_USED:        0
PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0          MALLOC_SIZE:        0

** MEMINFO in pid 7908 [org.abc.sdktest:abcSDKTestService] **
                 Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
              ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap     1754     1576        0     1880     5320     4132     1187
Dalvik Heap     1101      976        0     2680     7122     5390     1732
Dalvik Other      244      244        0        0                           
      Stack      176      176        0        0                           
  Other dev        5        0        4        0                           
   .so mmap      299       68        0     2868                           
  .apk mmap      168        0      140        0                           
  .dex mmap     1532        0     1448        0                           
  .oat mmap     1275        0        0        0                           
  .art mmap     2130      604        8        0                           
 Other mmap        4        4        0        0                           
    Unknown       78       76        0      160                           
      TOTAL     8766     3724     1600     7588    12442     9522     2919

Objects
             Views:        0         ViewRootImpl:        0
       AppContexts:        3           Activities:        0
            Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
     Local Binders:        4        Proxy Binders:       19
     Parcel memory:       32         Parcel count:       42
  Death Recipients:        0      OpenSSL Sockets:        0

SQL
       MEMORY_USED:        0
PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0          MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```

Comment: Post your service code so that it can be optimised dude

Comment: The service code itself is irrelevant and it's thousands of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause turned out to be from a conditional Toast display. Removing toast fixed the issue. Notifications do not cause the same phenomenon though. Apparently a Toast initializes viewroot and all the baggage with it like preloaded drawables. Although these preloaded drawables ideally should not be shown as private dirty memory as they belong to zygote, I guess if somehow they are not utilized by any other application it appears as my own memory footprint. So one has to remove UI elements in such case...